# Three.js: object isn't transformed when a matrix is applied to geometry

Tags: matrix, three.js, transformation, mesh

If I do so

```
mesh.applyMatrix(theMatrix);
render();
```

object is transformed (in a very strange way, but it does not matter here), but when I apply the matrix to a geometry as mrdoob [recommends](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1593#issuecomment-4718878)

```
mesh.geometry.applyMatrix(theMatrix);
render();
```

object is transformed only the first time. I can't make it moved dynamically, for example, when a trackbar is sliding.

What have I missed?

Three.js r.58

**Update**

I noticed that it happens only when WebGL renderer is used. With canvas renderer the object is transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set some mesh/geometry flags to `true` to tell three.js to update -- have you tried this as described at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates ?

Comment: I noticed that it happens only when WebGL renderer is used. With canvas renderer the object is transformed.

Answer (score 0):

yeah when you set your object matrix, it works. but when three.js render the scene it will recalculate the matrix according the object's position, scale, rotation. if your donot want to autoupdate the matrix, just set `object.matrixAutoUpdate to false.`

Comment: Do not set `matrixAutoUpdate = false` unless you are familiar with the inner-workings of the library and understand the consequences of doing so.